# Can super glue be used to attach an SSD to a metal holder?

Tags: ssd

I bought an [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSD), and it doesn't fit as my computer has a 3.5-inch hard disk drive. Can I use superglue to attach it to the metal hard disk drive holder or should I buy and adapter and wait?

Comment: As SSDs have no moving parts, I usually just put them somewhere into the case without any fixture.

Comment: Just purchase a converter bracket.

Comment: Superglue traditionally only works on porous surfaces, which metal is not.

Comment: @Bert Actually, the reverse is what is true for typical superglues. I'm sure there are types meant for porous materials, though.

Comment: My computer also didn't have an SSD bay... Simply just let it sit on the bottom of my computer case, as @Gene said. Had no issues for years. Be careful when you move your PC, though!

Comment: Try just screwing it in place with a single screw.

Comment: Hot glue. It's more flexible and can be removed.

Comment: "Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users". I don't know which of them would ask such a question...

If you really want to fix your SSD in position use a cable strap or duct tape until your adapter arrives. Or use some screws, most SSDs have mounting holes on their bottom side.

Comment: One thing you don't want to do is leave it dangling, unless the box will be rarely moved or bumped.  The shock that occurs when a loose component bangs against something is enormous -- much greater than what occurs with any sort of mounting.

Comment: This, unfortunately—and as we can clearly observe—is a bikeshed question where everyone has their own opinion about what to do, and a factual, correct answer cannot be given.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would use something semi-permanent. Double sided tape, [Velcro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velcro) or even some [zip ties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_tie) (tie wraps). Even if it is secured with one screw it is better than it hanging loose - it doesn't matter if it's hanging at an angle, upside down or back to front so long as the connectors and leads are 'comfortable'. The drive may be fine loose, but one thing to consider is the connector can actually wear if the drive is not secured.

Comment: Velcro tape (velcro with a sticky back) works well for SSDs.

Comment: I've mounted SSDs using ordinary scotch tape with no problem.

Comment: I've "mounted" an Intel SSD by just letting it hang from the cable without any problems for certainly over a year (or sure I wanted to fixate it with ductape but hey I'm busy). Those things weigh next to nothing and SATA adapters aren't that fragile.. the biggest problem of this method is that it encumbers the airflow more.

Comment: You can let it hang loose and insert some styrofoam blocks in the gaps to prevent it from sliding.

Answer (score 31):

Personally, I'd suggest that you buy the adapter and wait!

If you really HAVE to get the thing in and working - just install and use it wihtout glueing it - an SSD doesn't have moving parts, so its perfectly safe to install and run without needing to fix it in place and then when the proper chassis converter arrives, you can attach it to the case - just remember to not move or kick your base unit in the mean time!

While super glue will work and do what you need it to and will not damage the drive, you will be unable to remove the drive without damaging both the drive and drive bay/case when it comes to swapout time.

Just think - what if you find you need a bigger drive? What if the drive fails? what if you change case?  Its really not woreth it for the sake of waiting a day.  If its that vital - pay for quick shipping!

Comment: What's wrong with kicking your case before you get a converter?  I don't see how it can damage an SSD.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman: A falling block of silicon and attached cables inside a running computer could go wrong. Simple example, imagine if the cable got in the way of a fan!

Comment: @Phoshi aha, fair enough.. but usually hard drives are enclosed in a section that separates them from the motherboard so that's of little risk.  My SSD is attached to an adaptor which doesn't fit, so it's basically hanging loose inside my case.. never had any problems.

Comment: @CaptainCodeman - not all cases are as well designed as yours.  Its often seen in cases that the drives can slide front to back and drop down onto a fan, heatsink, RAM etc if not secured properly.

Comment: In addition to the oversight of future preparations, I think you should mention that gluing would very effectively insulate any areas that are glued, which might lead to overheating and damage.

Comment: @fredsbend I'm not sure what you mean by that. SSD's don't generate heat and a thin layer of glue is less than a 1/10 of a millimeter thick, so there isn't much insulation provided by the glue. If anything, it would ease heat transfer from any metal parts to the SSD.

Comment: SSD's do generate heat, just not as much as HDD's. When in a bracket, air flows freely around the drive on all sides, even though some areas are close to the bracket. If you seal any side with glue, there will be no more airflow on the drive. Instead, the air would first have to cool the bracket the drive is glued to.

Comment: @fredsbend The amount of heat generated by the SSD controller is really negligible. I doubt you could get one to overheat even if you were putting it into a bag.

Comment: Why not scotch tape in the meantime?

Answer (score 4):

Bought a £5 CD drive adapter (shaped like CD drive with the right connectors) which was about 1mm too large - and 1mm too large doesn't fit. Took the original CD drive, threw out the insides, used the electronics from the cheap adapter, and fit the SSD drive with strong double sided tape. Works perfect.

Without any case, I'd probably use double sided tape instead of superglue; I just would trust it more to last for a few years and be resistant to shock.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

SSDs are usually very light and they never exert dynamic forces on their mounts (as HDDs do), so almost any method of fixing them in place will work. But as others suggested, a permanent method, such as glue seems bit overkill, simply let it lie on the bottom of the case and order a proper bracket in the meantime.

As a side note, look on the back of your case motherboard mounting plate. Many cases have a "hidden" SSD mounting point there. Maybe you don't need any brackets after all. https://www.google.com/search?q=backside+ssd+mount&tbm=isch

Answer (score 3):

Definitely Not.

The reason is that super glue is extremely brittle and has no tolerance for lateral force. The thermal expansion of the case vs the SSD as it heats up and expands at a different rate than the case will make short work of any super glue bond.

Double sided foam tape is your best bet other than a proper adapter as it can bend as the metal expands/contracts without hurting its bond, don't use too much as you want airflow around it, a square in each corner should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on super glue because :

1. it gets "old" and fragile and if you try to move the chassis after an year it is possible that the SSD will bounce around and brake something else.
2. you will have problems moving the ssd if you want after.
3. the traces from the glue will void warranty.

If you are in extreme emergency try attaching it with plastic or other insulating cord-like material until you get it done properly. Otherwise do not do such a thing to your computer :)

Answer (score -1):

Take care about fixing it in place though. Since the connector does not have any locker nothing blocks it from just going out. The SATA connector is not tight itself, it easily disconnect with slight movement. In order to avoid data corruption and/or SSD drive failure it is highly recommended to fix it in place.

Even if you freely put on the surface it can creep out after some time because of the vibration.

Fix it anyway until holder arrives.

Comment: Some SATA cables actually do have clips. And most fit fairly snugly, assuming you don't yank it - if yours are disconnecting with slight movement, I'd say there's something wrong with your cables or drives. Though securing the drive is a good idea regardless.

Answer (score -1):

No. Superglue needs moisture to harden. It does not work over large surfaces where air cannot get to. Use some glue that hardens chemically (epoxy, marine silicone)

Answer (score -1):

Does the SSD expect the metal case of the drive to be electrically coupled to the grounded metal of the computer case?  If so, superglue wouldn't provide that ground and may cause problems down the line.

I don't know enough about the electrical works inside a PC to be able to say if this is actually a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use superglue because it will become fragile and eventually crack as the case vibrates.

Try rubber bands, instead: http://lifehacker.com/378786/silence-your-hard-drive-with-elastic-suspenders

EDIT: I know that SSDs don't make noise. I suggested this simply as a mounting method, regardless of the "silent" effects.

Comment: SSD's do not have moving parts thus this 'silencing trick' is unnecessary.

Comment: I did not recommend it for silencing purposes, simply as an alternative mounting strategy.

Answer (score -1):

The hazard with superglue is that it gets hard and brittle over time, especially with heating.  Eventually the thermal stresses will cause the joint to fail -- probably not in days or weeks, but easily months or a year or two.

Answer (score -1):

Supergluing will void the warranty.  Regardless of whether it might work, this is a decent enough reason on it's own not to do it.

Comment: How come? It's just some stuff on the outside. Any source?

Comment: Read your warranty.  The wording will vary from manufacturer to manufacturer but for example IBM/Hitachi define physical damage as Foreign material (e.g., adhesive, oil, dirt, gum), Damaged covers, Dents of any kind, Missing parts, Evidence of tampering